# Saving array of data to Firebase with Javascript/NodeJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to save data to the database but at a certain index. I tried pulling the data down with

```
var people = [];
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                var ID = childSnapshot.key;
                childSnapshot.forEach(function(lastSnapshot) {
                    var qr = lastSnapshot.val();
                    people.push({[ID]: qr});
                    return true; 
                });                
            });
```

My firebase structure:

```
people: {
    jake: "231",
    jessica: "412",
    rachel: "112"
}
```

Then I splice the list and add someone at a certain index:

```
index = 1; // add person after jessica
people.splice(index, 0, person);
```

I want to sync this back up to Firebase but set and update don't allow a format like this.

How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: There are no indexes in your JSON snippet, only named keys: `jake`, `jessica` and `rachel`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah that's on purpose. I just want the names and then I can just use javascript to splice it.

Comment: But in that case there is no sense inserting an item at a certain index. If you want to store `karl`, you just do `ref.child("karl").set("432")` and it ends up between `jessica` and `rachel` (when ordered by key).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Oh I see your confusion, no the number has nothing to do with the order. Like imagine it as people standing in line, I want to preserve the queue of first come first serve.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That doesn't change the basic problem though: the data structure you have in Firebase has no indexes. Can you write up a jsbin that has the minimal code reproduces the problem? Maybe that gets us on the same page.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Does it have to have an index? Doesn't firebase save and read chronologically?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things. If you don't specify an order when reading data, the data is returned ordered by key (or priority). Since keys are alphanumeric, they are ordered lexicographically, unless they look like array indices. Since your keys don't look like array indices, they are in lexicographical order. If your keys are generated using the Firebase `push()` method, they will indeed be chronological, since `push()` generates keys that are chronologically ordered when you use lexicographical sorting. But `jake`, `jessica` and `rachel` are not push IDs.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen So I restructured it to where `jake`, `jessica, and `rachel` all have their own parent push id. So `randompushid: { rachel: "112"}`. Now how can I insert someone before someone else on this queue?

Comment: You can't. Push ids are chronological on the time where you call `push()`. It sounds like you want to add a `timestamp` or `index` property to each user and then sort on that with `ref.orderByChild("index").on(...`.